# Is there some byte combination that can be used as a separator of streams of Int16

Tags: stream, language-agnostic, byte, separator

I was given the task to specify a file format for internal use inside an application.

One of the intended requirements says:

> The data section of the file should be made up of a series of streams of type `Int16` values (short integers), delimited by a suitable combination of one or more bytes.

As I understand, `Int16` can contain *any* single byte value, so I don't know how I could choose some sequence of bytes that is guaranteed not to appear incidentally inside a stream. Is there such a sequence?

(And also, if the answer is "no", what would be a good way to determine the position and size of each stream in the file?)

Answer (score 2):

By "streams," I assume the request indicates that the length is unknown when the writing of the data begins.

Therefore, I'd suggest a "chunked" encoding, where each substream is parcelled out into variable-size pieces, with the length of each piece written at the beginning as a fixed size integer. An empty chunk signals the end of the substream. Normally, there would be a maximum length of a chunk to facilitate allocation of buffers for efficient reading and writing.

This is patterned after HTTP's ["chunked" transfer encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1) and a similar approach is used in many other formats, such as the indefinite length encoding supported by the [basic encoding rules for ASN.1.](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fluca.ntop.org%2FTeaching%2FAppunti%2Fasn1.html&ei=lVsIVfHmMIT4yQSdroHgDA&usg=AFQjCNGoHCycqo_BntoD2ExCwIa4YCTbcw&sig2=4RpQFwilFKa_aOfoJ1cPhQ&bvm=bv.88198703,d.aWw)

Comment: You assumed right. This file format is meant for incremental writing (appending) during a data-acquisition session. Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest prefixing each stream with a length field, rather than trying to use delimiters, for the reason you've already given (no suitable unique delimiter). E.g.:

```
<length>
<stream>
<length>
<stream>
<length>
<stream>
...
```

where `<length>` is, say, a 4 byte integer which defines the number of 16 bit elements in the following stream.